# How to compare two dataframes columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
style.use("fivethirtyeight")
df_2010=pd.read_csv("c:/users/ashub/downloads/documents/MLB 2010.csv",index_col=0)
#print(df_2010)
sliced_data=df_2010[["Home Team","Away Team","Home Score","Away Score"]]
#print(sliced_data)
for win in sliced_data:
    flag1=sliced_data["Home Team"]+str("index")
    flag2=sliced_data["Away Team"]+str("index")
    print(sliced_data["Home Score"],sliced_data["Away Score"])
    if sliced_data["Home Score"]>sliced_data["Away Score"]:
        df_2010=df_2010.join([1,0],index=[flag1,flag2])
    else:
        df_2010=df_2010.join([0,1],index=[flag1,flag2])
df_2010.to_html("c:/users/ashub/desktop/ashu.html")
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

The error is at if condition when i am comparing the score of home team and away team.What I want to do is to add a column to the csv file which lists the win or loss of a team,win being 1 and loss being zero so that i can add the win of a particular team in a season and calculate their probability of winning and predict the probability of winning in the next season,

Comment: Can you add data sample?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1278lc1zanIKxIWzL6IH1ZzpqkjLeIP_m8Db_FxdBMZ4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you try to accomplish.

Comment: The error is at if condition when i am comparing the score of home team and away team.What  I want to do is to add a column to the csv file which lists the win or loss of a team,win being 1 and loss being zero so that i can add the win of a particular team in a season and calculate their probability of winning and predict the probability of winning in the next season.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create boolean mask by compare columns and then assign new columns:

```
np.random.seed(123)
sliced_data = pd.DataFrame([np.random.randint(0, 5, 5), 
                   np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)], 
                  index=['Home Score', 'Away Score']).T

m = sliced_data['Home Score'] > sliced_data['Away Score']


sliced_data['Away Team index'] = (~m).astype(int)
sliced_data['Home Team index'] = m.astype(int)

print(sliced_data)
   Home Score  Away Score  Away Team index  Home Team index
0           2           2                1                0
1           4           3                0                1
2           2           1                0                1
3           1           1                1                0
4           3           0                0                1
```

It is same as:

```
sliced_data['Away Team index'] = np.where(m, 0,1)
sliced_data['Home Team index'] = np.where(m, 1,0)

print(sliced_data)
   Home Score  Away Score  Away Team index  Home Team index
0           2           2                1                0
1           4           3                0                1
2           2           1                0                1
3           1           1                1                0
4           3           0                0                1
```

Comment: but this will always assign 1 to home team whereas i want to assign 1 to winning team

Comment: I test it with `sliced_data = pd.DataFrame([np.random.randint(0, 5, 5), 
                   np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)], 
                  index=['Home Score', 'Away Score']).T` and it works, maybe some problem in data?

Comment: i add sample and simplify solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903414/adding-specific-team-score-in-pandas

Answer (score 2):

You can do just this:

```
df_2010['Win'] = df_2010['Home Score'] > df_2010['Away Score']
```

You won't need that sliced data frame.

Here's a full example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.randint(0, 5, 5), 
                   np.random.randint(0, 5, 5)], 
                  index=['Home Score', 'Away Score']).T

print(df)

df['Win'] = df['Home Score'] > df['Away Score']

print(df)
```

Which will add to

```
   Home Score  Away Score
0           3           3
1           4           2
2           4           1
3           4           4
4           4           2
```

an additional column `win` like this:

```
   Home Score  Away Score    Win
0           3           3  False
1           4           2   True
2           4           1   True
3           4           4  False
4           4           2   True
```